# construct the `xpath` to allow argument

Tags: xpath, robotframework

User can drag the slider to different value from `aria-valuenow="1"`  to `aria-valuenow="30"`

The web element:

```
<div tabindex="0" class="ant-slider-handle" role="slider" aria-valuemin="1" aria-valuemax="30" aria-valuenow="7" aria-disabled="false" style="left: 20.6897%; right: auto; transform: translateX(-50%);" xpath="1"></div>
```

I plan to have test case like this:

```
*** Test Cases ***
001_Move-Slider
   [Arguments]     ${aria-valuenow}
   Click    ${slider}     10
```

I am not sure how to construct the xpath of `${slider}` to allow flexibility to enter `any value from 1 - 30`.

Comment: add id to the slider and then you can access it with that id without knowing the value ..

Comment: @rasjani can you explain more?